# How to read parquet file from AWS S3 bucket using R without downloading it locally?

Tags: r, amazon-s3, parquet

I'm able to download the parquet file from AWS S3 bucket on local and then read from it (see the below code). But is there any way that I can directly read parquet file from S3 and read, without storing in local?

````
save_object("Financial_Sample.parquet", file = "Financial_Sample.parquet", bucket = 'my-bucket')
df <- read_parquet("Financial_Sample.parquet")```
````

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the arrow package: https://arrow.apache.org/docs/r/index.html

It can directly read from s3 and even filter before reading using some dplyr verbs.